# How to get around Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant stuck at 99%

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

(I know there are threads on this, but the site won't let me comment on them and respond to the answers cited there which don't work for me)

I have:

- turned off Windows Updates (although it is up to date on Windows 7)
- turned off anti-virus and other security tools
- removed all external devices other than mouse

I have 100s of GB of free space.

I'm now on my 4th install attempt. It redownloaded each time - just as well I have unlimited downloads because it would be very expensive otherwise. It sits on 99% for five hours or so and then reboots or shuts down the machine. When I restart, it's as if the WUA had never run before.

Comment: Answered [elsewhere on this site](http://superuser.com/questions/1087029/windows-10-upgrade-assistant-stuck-at-99) . [Anthony Cappucci](http://superuser.com/users/606204/anthony-cappucci)'s answer worked best for me, on two Windows 7 boxes. Briefly, after turning off Windows updates, reboot, then stop the update server (in an admin CMD window, "net stop wauaserv"). Then run the Windows 10 Upgrade assistant.

Answer (score 1):

I got stuck at 99% several times. After I gave up the sloppy/lazy approach, I did the following with a little help from this link:

http://www.groovypost.com/howto/what-to-do-windows-10-upgrade-fails/

Moved my Downloads and Documents folders back to my user folder

Uninstalled NOD32

Disk Cleanup, including system files

Stopped Windows Update service

Set Windows Update to never check

Deleted the all the files and folders in Software Distribution

Deleted the entire Windows 10 upgrade folder

Configured a clean boot

Restarted

Returned to this link:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10/?wa=wsignin1.0

Held my breath and selected “update now”

The download took half an hour. By the time I went to bed an hour later, the install was at 26%. When I woke up, four hours later, I was greeted with “Welcome to Windows 10.”

I’m sure some of what I did was overkill, but you can’t argue with results. I suspect the clean boot turned the trick. I’ll do a clean install later, after the Anniversary Update.

Comment: According to answers in other question, the important part is `Stopped Windows Update service`

Comment: @Topera Stopping Windows Update service was the first thing I tried. Then I tried it a few more times just to be sure, along with every other suggestion littering help forums worldwide. Adding the clean boot seems to be what turned the tide.